# Use CreateWindow(Ex) to create a dummy parent control (like a panel)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, panel

So basically, I have a Tab Control (`WC_TABCONTROL`) and I want to place all of the controls that go with a single tab page on a single window (control, if you will, or panel). I want to create something like the panel in wxWidgets, so that when I call `ShowWindow(panel, SW_HIDE)`, I can hide the panel and all controls inside it. I hope you understand. Thanks, Grant.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a borderless, captionless dialogbox. I've used that very thing with tab-controls. Show and hide them on the tab control click events.

Actually some tab-controls will use the caption of the dialogbox in their own caption. YMMV.

Here's an old-school example. It shows all the basics.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760551%28VS.85%29.aspx

HTH

Comment: I'm developing a OOP wrapper, so I don't want to use .rc files.